# Not picking up 2nd vm

Tags: virtual-machine

Hi good day cut a long story short I am trying to run two vms on two different pcs as my main pc can t handle them both running at the same time do my current setup is

Dell(main pc) running parrot os in vm

Crappy laptop running durp n stink in vm

Both on same Wi-Fi both share internet connection via shared connection under Wi-Fi options shared but the problem I am facing is when I do any scan on network e.g. Netdiscover nmap etc i can pick up everything else on the network

Phones xbox the laptop running Windows 7 but I can't actually pick up the Ubuntu os that's running in vm

I forgot to mention they  are running virtual box latest version and  both are setup to allow vm under network settings plus both set to bridged